# Clarification about chatrooms' retention

Tags: discussion, support, chat

There are slightly similar questions like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123098/minimum-number-of-messages-after-which-a-chat-room-is-never-deleted/123101), but still, the [FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention) states that:

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person
>   actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if
>   it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

This wording has several issues in my opinion:

- according to discussions in comments (some deleted) in this question, chat rooms can be archived, in which case they become *frozen* i.e. immutable. It is far from obvious from the FAQ above.
- important terms are loosely defined, never making an explicit difference between *exist* and *be retained*. In my understanding, the former means that the room is still active and can be fully interacted with while the latter means it has been archived and is now read-only.
- it is not clear what *actively talking means*. Does it mean being present in the room ? Being present in the room and having posted a recent message ? If so, how recent ?

My proposed wording would be the following:

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person
>   actively talking in the room. Once all users have left the room, it
>   will either be deleted or archived after X days without any activity.
>   A chat room is eligible to archival if it has a total of at least 15
>   messages from two distinct users. Once archived, a chat room becomes
>   *frozen*, meaning than no new message can be added or deleted. Archived rooms are read-only for documentation purposes.

Does anyone feel like it would improve the FAQ ? What is the process for making such updates to the FAQ ?

Answer (score 5):

As long as there is a user in the room, that room is active and won't be removed.

If there is no one in the room, the room is allowed to be either archived or deleted; if there is at least 15 messages from at least two users, the room will never be deleted, only ever archived.

Comment: Active meaning that they have a tab for the room open in their browser, or meaning they posted a message at least as recent as X ? Also I may be playing on words, but do you recognize the FAQ is lacking a logical connector between the two sentences (which your phrasing isn't) ?

Comment: @Dici Meaning their profile picture is in the list of people in the room.

Comment: Which I think means they need to have the tab open, so *active* would mean currently present in the room

Comment: I'm having a conversation spanning on several days and the room has not been frozen or deleted even though it has been empty for the larger part of the recent days (at night for example). Therefore, the criteria for keeping a room active cannot be that at least one user is constantly logged in, there must be some minimum time X which is unspecified in the FAQ and right now I can't know exactly what I should do to prevent the room from being frozen (coming back every day ? Every 8 hours ?). I don't care that much about the room, just pointing out the FAQ is not answering those questions.

Comment: @Dici You are guaranteed that the room will stay active for as long as there is someone active in it.  It's not guaranteed that the second someone leaves the room will be archived or deleted.